# Pre-filtering a Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, powerbi, odbc

I am running into an issue with pre-filter a left outer join.

My database has several million records in an invoice header table and an invoice line table. Data transfer is very slow due to ODBC. I want to pull out recent invoice details. I can execute SQL queries against the source to ensure 'data-folding' happens at the source to minimize transfer volume. However, when I perform a left outer join between the two tables combined with "WHERE", the filter is applied after the left out join executes against the entirety of the left outer table. I want the outer table to be filtered before joining to the right.

Here is a sample of my SQL so far. It is formatted to be compatible with my ODBC source.

```
SELECT * 
FROM {oj "Invoice Archive Header" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Invoice Archive Line Items" 
ON "Invoice Archive Header".'INVOICE_NUMBER' = "Invoice Archive Line Items".'ODBC_INVOICE_NUMBER'
AND "Invoice Archive Header".'INVOICE_DATE' = "Invoice Archive Line Items".'ODBC_INVOICE_DATE'}
```

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: if the `WHERE` does not mention any column from "Invoice Archive Line Items" any database would filter using the main table only. Is the `WHERE` using columns from the second table as well?

Comment: Your query has no `WHERE` clause which makes it inconsistent with the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think the `WHERE` predicates are applied in a second step, after the query is defined in PowerBi (but I may be wrong).